# Combining grep and find for desired results

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to list files found from a script as "File Size - Path". What my script needs to filter is whenever I give it TWO parameters and the first one is "`-u`", then the files I'll be looking for are the ones that contain the word "Priority" at the beginning of the file. (The second parameter is always a directory).

So far I have this:

```
    if [ "$1" = -u ]
    for i in `grep -ril ^Priority "$2"`
    do
    echo | ls -lh `grep -ril ^Priority "$i"` | cut -d" " -f5,9
    done
    fi
```

It returns that the end of the file was not expected on line 7.

However when I run this:

```
for i in `grep -ril ^Prioridad "$1"`
do
echo | ls -lh `grep -ril ^Prioridad "$i"` | cut -d" " -f5,9
done
```

Returns desired results.

How can I get the first one working with such results but using `-u` as first parameter and directory as second one?

Comment: I am not seeing any reference to 'find'?  The rest of your code is rather nasty, not to mention that if performing on other distributions the cut may well not show you what you are after.  What is the purpose of the grep inside the for loop?  You already have the file name stored in '$i'.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: if [ ] ; then <-- may be

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `ls` does not read its standard input, so the `echo | ls …` is most peculiar (unnecessary).

Comment: Note that your `grep` command looks for a line starting `Priority` or `Prioridad` anywhere in the file, not only for that item on line 1.  I'm not sure if that matters to you or not.  Also, it is generally better to use `$(grep …)` instead of back-ticks ```…`grep …`…```.  And not just because showing back-ticks in comments is a horrendous exercise.

Answer (score 3):

You missed `then`:

```
if [ "$1" = -u ]; then # <-- here
    for i in `grep -ril ^Priority "$2"`
    do
      # Some more edits and trying to remove the echo/ls
      # and battling against not found scenario
       if grep -ril ^Priority "$i" ; then # if exists 
          echo "$(stat -c%s $i) $i" # stat size and File
       fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Note my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385974/combining-grep-and-find-for-desired-results#comment81725838_47385974)